# How to change a button's title programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, nsindexpath

I have a Master-DetailView project and i need to change a button's title  by an array like i do here :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MapKit

class TemplateTestViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var ProfileMapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var BarOrClubLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var HeaderProfileName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var HeaderprofileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var StreetProfileLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ProfilePhoneNumberLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var WorkTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var AgeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Set Ups the Image Template :
        HeaderprofileImage.image = UIImage(named: ProfileImages[MyIndex])
        //Sets Up The BIG Name Template :
        HeaderProfileName.text = ProfileNames[MyIndex]
        //Sets Up The Navigation Bar Name :
        navigationItem.title = ProfileNames[MyIndex]
        //Sets Up Street Text :
        StreetProfileLabel.text = ProfileStreets[MyIndex]
        //Sets Up Bar Or Club Text :
        BarOrClubLabel.text = ProfileBarOrClub[MyIndex]
        //Sets Up Age Text :
        AgeLabel.text = AgeText[MyIndex]
```

## I TRIED :

```
ProfilePhoneNumberLabel.setTitle(ProfilePhoneNumbers[MyIndex], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

AND IT DIDNT CHANGE.

is there a way to do something like that ? and if so can someone show me how to ?
thanks ahead

Comment: Use the setTitle

Comment: @Mannopson look what i tried it didn't work for me

Comment: Where did you try that call to `setTitle`?

Comment: I tried didnt work for some reason

Comment: @rmaddy Does the title has to be plain to change by code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well....This is awkward but you have to set your UIButton title to Plain in storyboard to have it changed

```
ProfilePhoneNumberLabel.setTitle(PhoneNumbers[MyIndex], for: .normal)
```

+

Plain `UIButton` Title

=

Happy Camper

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you set the title for `ProfilePhoneNumberLabel`

```
ProfilePhoneNumberLabel.setTitle(PhoneNumbers[MyIndex], for: .normal)
```

The `for` parameter lets you set the text for the button in various states. In most cases, setting the title for the `normal` state should be enough.

Comment: This is the same code posted in the question. How does this solve the problem?

Comment: yep , didn't work for me already

Comment: Does the title has to be plain to change by code?

Comment: Yes, it should be plain — I didn’t realize that your button wasn’t. I see from another answer that you got it working. Good luck with your project!